# install xdebug on ubuntu to one directory

Tags: ubuntu, xdebug

How do I install xdebug on ubuntu to one directory?

I've tried adding the confing for xdebug in a php.ini file in the root of the site but this did nothing to override the defaults which are set when the extension is loaded via /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

I have a live site and a dev site on the server and I don't want to enable xdebug on the live site.

Comment: How are you running php?  mod_php, cgi, fastcgi, or something else?

Comment: @Zoredache I'm running it as mod_php